# jQuery Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

i am using $.post ajax method to run a function which returns an array. 
When the array is returned back to the $.post method at that time i get the error :

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input

This is my $.post method

```
$.post(
     ajax_url('showResult'),{
         search_type:search_type,
         search_criteria:search_criteria
     },function(d){
       var ary = $.parseJSON(d);
});
```

And this is my ajax function which returns array

```
function showResult()
{
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $search_type = $jinput->get('search_type','','STRING');
    $search_criteria = $jinput->get('search_criteria','','STRING');
    $search_type = trim($search_type);
    $search_criteria = trim($search_criteria);

    if(!empty($search_type))
    {
        if($search_type == "Search by Name")
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = "SELECT * FROM #__product";
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->query();
            $result = $db->loadAssocList();
            $result = json_encode($result);
            echo ($result);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

What should i do to solve this error?

Comment: Have you read this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post ?

Comment: Try console logging just `d` and see what you've got, it's probably not JSON ?

Comment: @adeneo i get empty result in console.log(ary)

Comment: Manually construct the URL and view it in a browser, do you get the expected result set back?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = json_encode($result);
```

$result might be empty.

check it out.

Comment: now i have put values in $result and tried but still the same problem

Comment: Please add some more details as to why this should help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe your $return isn't a json.**

Try this

```
Debug the $return strcture.

<?php
//add this line before exit;
var_dump($result);

?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post(
ajax_url('showResult'),{
        search_type:search_type,
        zarch_criteria:search_criteria
},
function(d){
    console.log(d);
    //^
    //+------ add this line
    var ary = $.parseJSON(d);
});
</script>
```

Comment: console.log(d) returns empty value

Comment: so, this throw Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of input.It means your php variables $return is empty, **try return a $return = "{null:''}" when the $return is empty to avoid this error.:D**

Comment: still same Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery1.9.1.js:3
b.extend.parseJSON jquery1.9.1.js:3
(anonymous function) common.js:90
c jquery1.9.1.js:3
p.fireWith jquery1.9.1.js:3
k jquery1.9.1.js:5
r

Comment: what you get from console.log?